# Restrict python script access to os functions

Tags: python, security, permissions, exec, eval

I need a fresh idea from you, any help is appreciated.

I am implementing a system where user would be able to upload his own Python scripts and execute them within one of servers.

I do beware about the security issues. I would like to restrict any access to the operating system from this script.

First of all the script get verified with the `ast` parser to disallow access to many most obvious keywords like `exec`, `import`, `open`, etc.

User can declare usage of some libraries though. One of important ones is `pandas` library (also I have to provide `matplotlib`, `numpy` and others). I have implemented 'proxy' objects, imitating modules, but providing access to ony limited set of attributes. For example I can provide a proxy object `json`,  but access to functions `loads` or `dumps` is not allowed.

Most obvious attempts to get an attribute from any object by names `os`, `sys`, etc are not allowed too. This way I am trying to close a hole when a user try to access `os` module with `json.os` or like this.

This can work, but it is a simple shield. I can review all modules and disallow access to most of the dangerous functions, but even one missed might lead to a potential damage. Also, some modules may be accessed with a tricky way like `pandas.tools.util.pd` will refer to the original `pandas` module. I'll spend a year to close everything..

I thought about restricting access on the file system level, but the script runs with `eval` function within the main process (`celery`-based) and has the same permissions (and same user) as main process. Theoretically it can read all the sources and pass them to the user.

One of my ideas is to run the script in a separate process with minimal set of sources and permissions, and pass the data to/from it with pipes. But this will require to refactor a lot of code and the stability is not guaranteed - I still need a lot of code around to make it working.

Comment: how did you manage to get the output from the code?

Comment: also how did you manage to restrict memory and cpu usage?

Comment: @john-balvin-arias no way, I didn't. This was a probability to get OOM and high cpu usage with the script. The whole idea was wrong. If I do this project now - I'd start using containers.

Comment: as for the output - this is simple - you either allow to use pre-defined logger object or simply redirect sys.stdout to something manageable.

Comment: " I'd start using containers." wouldn't that be the same trouble with cpu usage? because  when deploying the code to the container it can't be regulate how much ram and cpu it should use for each individual deployment, I'll need to create nodes specific for each code, wouldn't that be inneficient?, also would you use RestrictedPython ? I need to use panda, numpy and others

Comment: @john-balvin-arias no, for Docker for example you can set max allowed resources for each container.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[RestrictedPython](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/RestrictedPython/) is what you need.